# unauthenticated packages

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install openfoam 4 on my Ubuntu 16.04, but when I typed this command:

```
 sudo apt-get -y install openfoam4
```

I encountered this error:

```
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
```

How can I fix this? I should also mention that I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What's the full output of that command? What's the output of `apt-cache policy openfoam4`?

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```
 sudo apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install openfoam4
```

There will be no error now.

However do remember that installation of unauthenticated packages is a great security risk. Do it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing you what to do to address the issue (add `--allow-unauthenticated` to your commandline).

To avoid having this error you can use `apt-key` to authenticate the repository.

The command format is:

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys [key]
```

Replace `[key]` with the authentication key provided by the distributor of the package.

For OpenFOAM 4 you can perform this authentication automatically using the supplied command from their site:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu
$ sudo sh -c "wget -O - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
```

Some details of this is provided by Openforum for their Ubuntu install at:
http://openfoam.org/download/4-0-ubuntu/

The above command will remove the error and other warnings concerning security when updating and upgrading your system packages.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the man page 
`man apt-get`:

`-y, --yes, --assume-yes`

Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. 
**If an undesirable situation, such as**
changing a held package, **trying to install a unauthenticated
package** or removing an essential package **occurs then apt-get will
abort.** Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Comment: Consider the fact that the pakage is unauthenticated

Comment: @rancho yes my bad. I edited the answer just to provide information on why this happens.